# Activesync sendmail command for 12.1 protocol version?

Tags: exchange-server, activesync

Is sendmail command available for 12.1 protocol version? According to me it is available for 14.0+ version. So i am wondering is there any other alternate command for the same?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178477(v=EXCHG.80).aspx), it is available.

"For protocol versions 2.5, 12.0, and 12.1, the body of the SendMail request is the MIME representation of the message to be sent. In this case, the client sets the Content-Type header to "message/rfc822"."